# to insert data in google visualization bar charts charts using for loop in django

Tags: python, django, linux, google-visualization, ubuntu-10.04

I am currently working on a project in django. In this project I want to show graphical representation of data stored in the sqlite3 database tables. For that I have written some piece of code in which I want to add the table values in the chart using for loop someting like this way :(here list1 contains all the values of the table and this page is redirected to show this graphical result)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['FileName', 'Frequency'],
          {% for l in list1 %}
               [{{l.file_name}},{{l.frequency_count}}], 
          {% endfor %}
          ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Search Performance',
            hAxis: {title: 'FileName', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
         };

         var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nothing is getting displayed on the server. Why?

Please Help. I'm new to django and javascripts. so , please please help

Comment: What is the question/issue/problem?

Comment: @Rohan : can you help me at this ? you asked me the issue, the issue is nothing is getting displayed on the server , what is the problem

Comment: Did you try firebug or chrom dev tools to see if there is any error?

Comment: @rohan : no, I have'nt used them. Can you tell me one more thing , do you see any error in my code otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I need to put the quotes around {{l.file_name}} i.e. it should have been '{{l.file_name}}' and it worked. Remember always if you have data at axis as string, as it is in my case, always put it in the quotes either ' or " .